# Why does this case lead to a contradiction?

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

From Mac Lane's Category theory:

Concerning the last line of the proof, I see why having card$(J) \gt$ card arr$(C)$ leads to a contradiction because it shows a category has more arrows that itself which is a contradiction, but why does the case where card$(J) \le$ card arr$(C)$ lead to a contradiction as well?

---

[image]

Comment: The clou is that this construction can be made for **any** small set $J$. So to arrive at the contradiction just start with one that indeed has a cardinality larger than arr(C).

Comment: @drhab What do you mean by "the clou"?

Comment: Something like: "the spot that seems to be out of your skope so causes your lack of understanding"

Comment: As far as MathJax goes, you might find the command `\operatorname{}` helpful in beautifying your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that $C$ is not a preorder must lead here to a contradiction. This to justify the conclusion that $C$ is a preorder.

This can be done as sketched in the proof working with a small set $J$ that has a cardinality that exceeds the cardinality of the arrow set of $C$.

Comment: But what if you assume that the cardinality of $J$ is less than the cardinality of the arrow set of $C$?

Comment: Then it doesn't work, but so what? There are sets $J$ that **do work**, and that is enough to come to the contradiction.

Comment: But why doesn't it work, what does it contradict?  That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Your question is: "why does the case where card(J)$\leq$ card(C) lead to a contradiction as well?" I am telling that that case does *not* lead to a contradiction. And also that that fact is not an obstacle in proving that $C$ is a preorder. Simply because there are sets $J$ that do lead to a contradiction. That is enough.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was misunderstanding what was being contradicted.  So the contradiction lies not in the particular size of $J$, but in the fact that it's assumed previously that ANY $J$ should work which is contradicted by finding one that does not work.

Comment: Amen!!!!!!!!!!!!!!